# Is there a way to determine the tag of the workRequest that is active?

Tags: android, android-workmanager, android-background

Can the tag of the unique `workRequest` that executed the `doWork()` function of the `worker` class be determined from inside the `doWork` function. When using firebase jobdispatcher there was a `jobParameters` paramater where `job.gettag()` could be used to get the tag.

Comment: Create an unique task and specify a tag

Comment: You can look into this video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-prIcKMlrYQ) for creating an observer

Comment: i already have tags on my `uniquePeriodicWorkRequests`. In the video you linked there is no mention of how to resolve this. I dont think `WorkInfo` can tell you which request called the funtion

Answer (score 2):

You can use WorkInfo to check if a certain tag is active.

```
WorkManager instance = WorkManager.getInstance();
    ListenableFuture<List<WorkInfo>> statuses = instance.getWorkInfosByTag(tag);
    try {
        boolean running = false;
        List<WorkInfo> workInfoList = statuses.get();
        for (WorkInfo workInfo : workInfoList) {
            WorkInfo.State state = workInfo.getState();
            running = state == WorkInfo.State.RUNNING | state == WorkInfo.State.ENQUEUED;
        }
```